# HTML - Centering a picture in banner issues

Tags: html, image, css, css-position

For some reason I can't seem to get the picture to center. I have to be able to center the banner picture with the background picture behind it. Usually I can use the margin-left and margin-right both on auto and it will work, but not this time it seems.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('background.png');
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}
#banner {
  background-image: url('bannerbg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.bannerimg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #999999;
  text-align: center;
}
#mainarea {
  height: 1100px;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 4px gray solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#minfo {
  float: right;
}
#rotper {
  width: auto;
  height: 83px;
  background-image: url('rbg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}
span {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
#ovimg {
  /*position:relative;
     left:192px;*/
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}
#w3c {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  /* margin-top:10px;*/
  clear: right;
  bottom: 90px;
}
.reviews {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-width: 47%;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 47%;
  /* Firefox */
  column-width: 47%;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2%;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 2%;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 2%;
  height: 790px;
  padding-left: 10pt;
  padding-top: 10pt;
}
p {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.rvws {
  background-color: #e8dc9b;
  border: 2px gray solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.pnumb {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: #a2b964;
  width: 700px;
  height: 42px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: 159px;
}
.crit {
  position: relative;
  clear: left;
}
/*.cname{
     text-align:justify;
     clear:right;
    }*/

dl {
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 688px;
  background-color: #a2b964;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}
dd {
  padding: 10px;
}
dt {
  padding-left: 10pt;
  padding-right: 10pt;
}
.top {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.troublesome {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
#rightcol {
  padding-top: 35pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="movie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="rotten.gif" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="banner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" class="bannerimg" />
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>
  <div id="mainarea">
    <div id="minfo">
      <div>
        <img src="overview.png" alt="general overview" / id="ovimg">
      </div>

      <dl>
        <dt class="top">STARRING</dt>
        <dd>Patrick Stewart
          <br />Mako
          <br />Sarah Michelle Gellar
          <br />Kevin Smith</dd>

        <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
        <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

        <dt>RATING</dt>
        <dd>PG</dd>

        <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
        <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

        <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
        <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

        <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
        <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

        <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
        <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

        <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
        <dd>90 mins</dd>

        <dt>GENRE</dt>
        <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

        <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
        <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

        <dt>LINKS</dt>
        <dd>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
    <div id="rotper">
      <img src="rottenbig.png" alt="Rotten" style="position:relative; left:15px;" />
      <span id="33">33%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews">
      <p class="rvws">
        <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
        <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
      </p>
      <p>
        <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Peter Debruge
        <br />Variety
      </p>

      <p class="rvws">
        <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
        <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
      </p>
      <p>
        <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Todd Gilchrist
        <br />IGN Movies
      </p>

      <p class="rvws">
        <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
        <q>It stinks!</q>
      </p>
      <p>
        <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Jay Sherman (unemployed)
      </p>

      <p class="rvws">
        <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
        <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
      </p>
      <p>
        <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Joshua Tyler
        <br />CinemaBlend.com
      </p>

      <p class="rvws">
        <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
        <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
      </p>
      <p>
        <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />NAME
        <br />PUBLICATION
      </p>
      <div id="rightcol">
        <p class="rvws">
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Jeannette Catsoulis
          <br />New York Times
        </p>

        <p class="rvws">
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Ed Gonzalez
          <br />Slant Magazine
        </p>

        <p class="rvws">
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
          <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Mark Palermo
          <br />Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)
        </p>

        <p class="rvws">
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />Steve Rhodes
          <br />Internet Reviews
        </p>


        <p class="rvws">
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" class="crit" />NAME
          <br />PUBLICATION
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="pnumb">(1-10) of 88</p>
  </div>
  <div id="w3c">
    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">
      <img src="w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
      <img src="w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add text-align:center to your banner class:

```
#banner{
    background-image:url('bannerbg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;


    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
margin:0 auto; 
display:block;
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You did not set horizontal-align attribute. So image's position isn't setted by your css.

As you used good programing style. I don't recomend to use the "deprecated" element:

`<center><yourimage-element /></center>`

but it is still posible while you write and test the correct ccs.

greetings

Comment: can't edit the HTML document only work with the CSS file